# Ignore additional keyword arguments in python

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument

Imagine I have a function like

```
def foo(x):
    ...
```

When I call it with the dictionary `{ 'x': 42, 'y': 23 }` as keyword arguments I get an `TypeError`:

```
>>> foo(**{ 'x': 42, 'y': 23 })
...
TypeError: foo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y'
```

Is there a good way to make a function call with keyword arguments where additional keyword arguments are just ignored?

**My solution so far:** I can define a helper function:

```
import inspect

def call_with_kwargs(func, kwargs):
    params = inspect.getargspec(func).args

    return func(**{ k: v for k,v in kwargs.items() if k in params})
```

Now I can do

```
>>> call_with_kwargs(foo, { 'x': 42, 'y': 23 })
42
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `def func1(x, **kwargs):`?

Comment: So altering `func1()` to use a catch-all is not an option, it has to work for *all* functions? e.g. `def func1(x, **kwargs):`?

Comment: not a solution but you can make a decorator out of your `call_with_kwargs` function

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, this would work fine in my case. Thanks a lot. If you want, you can add an answer to this question (so that I can accept it...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If altering your functions is fine, then just add a catch-all `**kw` argument to it:

```
def foo(x, **kw):
    # ...
```

and ignore whatever `kw` captured in the function.